# How to make change email address form in profile in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I did password change successfully but i had troubles for email change which i think it would be easier but for some reason couldn't think how to do it.

**Old email:**

**New email:**
**Confirm new email:**

This is the form i wanna make it but cant solve the Controllers function.

This is how i tried to solve it

```
public function changeemailPost(Request $request)
    {

        if (!(Hash::check($request->get('email'), Auth::user()->email))) {
            return redirect()->back()->with("error","Your current e-mail does not matches with the e-mail you provided. Please try again.");
        }

        if(strcmp($request->get('email'), $request->get('new-email')) == 0){
            return redirect()->back()->with("error","New e-mail cannot be same as your current e-mail. Please choose a different e-mail.");
        }

            $validate = $request->validate([
                'email' => 'required',
                'new-email' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            ]);
            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->email = $request['new-email'];
            $user->save();
            Auth::logout();
            return view('auth.login');
        }
```

**This is the html**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('change-emailPost') }}">
                            @csrf
                            <label>Enter your old e-mail:</label>

                            <fieldset class="youplay-input">
                                <input id="current-email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Current E-Mail" name="email" required>
                            </fieldset>

                            <label>Enter your new e-mail:</label>

                            <fieldset class="youplay-input">
                                <input id="new-email" type="email" placeholder="New E-Mail" class="form-control" name="new-email" required>
                            </fieldset>

                            <fieldset class="youplay-input">
                                <input id="new-email-confirm" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm New E-Mail" name="new-email-confirmation" required>
                            </fieldset>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default db">
                                Change E-Mail
                            </button>
                        </form>
```

**But i only get this error**

> Your current e-mail does not matches with the e-mail you provided. Please try again

**The problem got fixed thanks to the answer below but one thing you should change is the Hash checks for errors in email, instead of:**

```
if (!(Hash::check($request->get('email'), Auth::user()->email))) {
            return redirect()->back()->with("error","Your current e-mail does not matches with the e-mail you provided. Please try again.");
        }

        if(strcmp($request->get('email'), $request->get('new-email')) == 0){
            return redirect()->back()->with("error","New e-mail cannot be same as your current e-mail. Please choose a different e-mail.");
        }
```

**Use this:**

```
if(Auth::user()->email != $request['email']){
            return redirect()->back()->with("error","Your email doesnt not match with what you provided");
        }
        if(Auth::user()->email === $request['new-email']){
            return redirect()->back()->with("error", "Your new email cannot be the same as the old email");
        }
```

Comment: You are using Hash::check on the user email. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: There is a [process for reopening closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question). You noted on [the previous version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054388/how-to-make-change-email-address-form-in-laravel) that it was closed 'for some reason', that reason being that it "Needs details or clarity" as was clear from the fact that two people had asked you to post code. Now you have edited it, it's in the queue to be reviewed to see if it should be reopened, but you have preempted that by raising a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change your **changeemailPost** function. Try this -

```
public function changeemailPost(Request $request)
{

    if (!(Hash::check($request->get('email'), Auth::user()->email))) {
        return redirect()->back()->with("error","Your current e-mail does not matches with the e-mail you provided. Please try again.");
    }

    if(strcmp($request->get('email'), $request->get('new-email')) == 0){
        return redirect()->back()->with("error","New e-mail cannot be same as your current e-mail. Please choose a different e-mail.");
    }

        $validate = $request->validate([
            'new-email' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'new-email_confirmation' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->email = $request['new-email'];
        $user->save();
        Auth::logout();
        return view('auth.login');
    }
```

And your HTML like below -

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('change-emailPost') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <label>Enter your old e-mail:</label>

                        <fieldset class="youplay-input">
                            <input id="current-email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Current E-Mail" name="email" required>
                        </fieldset>

                        <label>Enter your new e-mail:</label>

                        <fieldset class="youplay-input">
                            <input id="new-email" type="email" placeholder="New E-Mail" class="form-control" name="new-email" required>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset class="youplay-input">
                            <input id="new-email-confirm" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm New E-Mail" name="new-email_confirmation" required>
                        </fieldset>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default db">
                            Change E-Mail
                        </button>
                    </form>
```

If you want to compare two input field `a & b` with value with `confirmed` validation rules `b` field should be renamed as `b_confirmation`.

Reference - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-confirmed

Comment: He's getting output from the first condition where he hash the provided email and compare it to the authentified user email

Comment: @reeves Sorry! missed that part. But I am not sure whether his email is stored in database as hashed or not.

Comment: Are you saving email address in database in plain text format or storing hash version of email?

Comment: i still get the error that my current email does not match with my provided email, maybe to handle errors i dont need to Hash check them?

Comment: i just fixed that with adding if(Auth::user()->email != $request['email']){
            return redirect()->back()->with("error","Your email doesnt not match with what you provided");
        }
        if(Auth::user()->email === $request['new-email']){
            return redirect()->back()->with("error", "Your new email cannot be the same as the old email");
        }